# Pull in random html page

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have a comic website www.twistedshotgun.com and it has a random button with some javascript someone made for me. I now need something that is easier to update.

I need the random button to choose a random html page, but I dont want to manually add each webpage to each html page, because as I make more pages it means changing every single individual page that has a random button to add the new content.

So is there a way to have an external file that lists all the random pages in one file so I can just update that?

I do not know javascript but this is my current code, but this is on every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//INDEX VERSION ONLY

//pages (use full url if in a different domain);

var page1 = "comics/101/longbear.html";
var page2 = "comics/102/do_bees_pump.html";
var page3 = "comics/103/how_I_feel_on_a_daily_basis.html";
var page4 = "comics/104/windows_8 _space oddity.html";

//array (add all the pages inside [])
var pages = [page1,page2,page3,page4];
function showRandomPage()
{
    var num = Math.round(Math.random() * (pages.length-1));
    window.location.href=pages[num];
    console.log(num);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the information about the random pages between sessions, store the list of the random pages in a database and access the database whenever you want to get to the random URL.

Another possibility is to store the list in Javascript, in an external file (depending on how long it is).

Comment: Great, Ive no idea how to do that though, any examples? I only know html and css.

Comment: create another javascript file and add that file to the HTML page, declaring the global variables in the file.  http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

Comment: Thanks, think that is beyond my skills, but will give it a go

Comment: If you're trying to do anything this complex in Javascript/HTML/CSS, I really recommend you go through the tutorials at www.codecademy.com

Comment: I just added a .js, then added the current JS to the the file and it seems to work like that? Cant quite understand the global variable part..

Comment: In Javascript, global variables are variables outside any of the methods.  They'll work for anything on the page.

Comment: ok, well its working without that global bit, Id never be able to add that sorry.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the pages are all in different directories, there is no need or benefit to them having different names, and as you'll see there's a lot of benefit in them being the same, so I recommend renaming your page files to the same name, which might as well be simply `index.html`.

If your pages have the same name, your random selection script becomes very simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showRandomPage() {
    var num = 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
    window.location.href = "comics/" + num + "/index.html";
    console.log(num);
};

</script>
```

If you number your directories sequentially from `100` on up (not skipping any numbers), all you need to do to maintain your code is increase the `4` in the code to whatever is quantity of pages you have.

Answer (score 0):

put your random generating page java script in a file with extension .js , say pagedatabase.js

now in your html page where you want to call the function 
place this code above it.

```
<script src="pagedatabase.js"></script>
```

it should work. id did for me. i too had the same problem with big database of header scripts.

keep in mind that the script call and the function call should be in the same region. do not place one in the head and other in the body. your html editor will give an error.